# Is there a way to disable Archiving?

Tags: gmail-labels

I often accidentally click on the "Archive" button  because it is the first button that pops up in messages.

I'm frustrated that there isn't a folder that shows archived messages or another quick way.

The "All Mail" folder isn't useful because it combines all incoming and outgoing messages together.

I have no use for threads and conversations, and because of it, I'm constantly getting my wires crossed trying to access individual messages.

Is there a way to disable archiving?

Answer (score 1):

## Conversation View

"Conversation View" (threaded messaging) is an optional feature, and can be turned off in Gmail as follows:

1. Navigate to the "General" tab in Gmail's "Settings"
    **Link:** [mail.google.com/mail/#settings/general](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/general)
2. Scroll down the page until you locate "Conversation View"
3. Select the "Conversation view off" option
   [image]
4. Scroll to the bottom of the page and save your changes

## Gmail Archive

A message that is "archived" simply means that it does not include the `INBOX` label.

If you want to search for an "archived" message, use

```
-in:inbox
```

To also exclude messages you sent, use

```
-in:inbox -in:sent
```

## All Mail

If you want an alternative to the "All Mail" folder, you can search received messages (archived or not) using *****
<sup><sub>***** *messages in* `SPAM` *and* `DELETED` *are excluded*</sub></sup>

```
-in:sent
```